# 3D annotated images to 3D KITTI Format

Tags: 3d, annotations, object-detection, bounding-box, kitti

I annotated 2D images using 3D Bounding boxes. Now, I want to **convert** this data's format **to KITTI dataset's Format**. Is there any way to do it?